# Python, multiple of 10 if statement

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

so I'm writing up a "stopwatch game" in python for a course I'm doing, and I want it so that when the timer stops on a whole number, the player receives a point.

I figure that a "whole number" will be a multiple of 10, as the format would be something like this a;bc:d, and the timer is running at a tenth of a second.

What I need your help for is how would I go about saying, "Oh hey, if he stops on a multiple of 10, give him a point".

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to put specify a multiple of 10.

Answer (score 17):

Use the `%` (modulo operation). Eg:

```
>>> 100%10
0
>>> 101%10
1
```

Basically, `x%y` returns the value of the remainder of `x/y`, so if the remainder is `0`, than `x` is evenly divisible by `y`. Therefore, if `x%10` returns something other than a zero, `x` is not divisible by 10.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about this, but couldn't quite wrap my head around it from how it was originally explained to me.

Comment: No problem. The mod operation definitely seems scarier than it is when you first learn it.

Answer (score 4):

You should try using a `modulo` in your script.

See :

```
>>> if not 10 % 10:
...     print "OK"
... 
OK
>>> if not 9 % 10:
...     print "OK"
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If a number is a multiple of 10, the remainder when you divide it by 10 will be 0. You can get the remainder of a division in Python by using the `%` operator. For example:

```
print 13 % 10  # 3
```

<sup>This is a slight oversimplification; `%` (modulus/modulo) is different than remainder for negative operands.</sup>