# How do you correctly test for divisibility in python

Tags: python

I wrote some code to evaluate the integers between x and y and check for divisibility by the integers 3 and 5.
This is the code.

```
def div_3_5(start, end):
    result = 0
    result2 = 0
    result3 = 0 
    while start < end:
        result2 = start + result 
        result = result2 - start + 1
        if result2 % 3==0 or 5==0:
            result3 = result3 + 1 
        else:
            result3 = result3 + 0
        return result3
```

I'm just a beginner but everything seems fine in the code of course unless I have used the "or" statement incorrectly or checked for divisibility incorrectly. Which brings me to the main question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nice way of rephrasing FizzBuzz :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

Comment: Would this be http://projecteuler.net/problem=1 ?

Comment: You've got an answer as to your main problem... but I'd like to add that your `result3 = result3 + 0` is fairly pointless.... You don't need the `else`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
if result2 % 3 == 0 or result2 % 5 == 0:
```

Otherwise it is parsed as `if (result2 % 3==0) or (5==0):`, which is clearly wrong as `5 != 0`.

Another suggestion which can be quite useful as you have more numbers you want to check for divisibility:

```
if any(result2 % i == 0 for i in (3, 5)):
```

---

This is a much simpler version of what you seem to be trying to do (Project Euler problem 1):

```
def div_3_5(start, end):
    return sum(1 for i in range(start, end+1) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)
```

Or, using De Morgan's laws and the fact that `0` is a `False`-ish value:

```
def div_3_5(start, end):
    return sum(1 for i in range(start, end+1) if not (i % 3 and i % 5))
```

Comment: +1 for ninja'ing.  Sometimes, Python can be a little bit *too* English; you've got to remember that Python will not read your mind.