# If Statement - Nested Conditional Using Modulus Operator in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, int, modulus

I need to create a program in Python that asks the user for a number, then tells the user if that number is even or if it's divisible by 5. If neither is true, do not print anything. For example:

```
Please enter a number: 5

    This number is divisible by 5!

Please enter a number: 7

Please enter a number: 20

    This number is even!

    This number is divisible by 5!
```

I tried to copy the method that was used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python), but I'm getting an error message on line 8:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 8) (if Num_1 % 2 == 0)
```

Here is my code:

```
#TODO 1: Ask for user input
Num1 = input("Please enter a number")
#TODO 2: Turn input into integer
Num_1 = int(Num1)
#TODO 2: Use conditionals to tell the user whether or not their
#number is even and/or divisible by 5

if Num_1 % 2 == 0
    print ("This number is even!")
        if Num_1 % 5 == 0 
            print ("This number is divisible by 5!")
```

Since I'm using the modulus operator to determine whether or not Num_1 is an exact multiple of 2, I should be returning a value of True and therefore should print "This number is even!" But instead I'm getting this error message - why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start of each Python block should end with a colon `:`. Also take note of the indentation.

```
Num1 = input("Please enter a number")
Num_1 = int(Num1)

if Num_1 % 2 == 0:
    print ("This number is even!")
    if Num_1 % 5 == 0:
        print ("This number is divisible by 5!")
```

Comment: Brilliant - didn't know that Python requires the start of each block to end with a colon. Same with your correction to the indentation - thank you.