# How to ask for a remainder, or a whole number in python?

Tags: python, factors

Im using pYcharm, Im stuck trying to make a program that requests a whole number greater than 1 as inut factors and then returns the prime numbers of the given int. Here is what i have so far:

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive whole number (<1):"))
f = 2
range = (1, number)
while number > 1:
    while f / number ## Does f divide by number without remainders? as in        
                           does in divide evenly?
        print(f)
        number /= f
    else:
        f += 1
```

The part I am stuck on, is how do I ask if f / number has a remainder or does it divide evenly?

Comment: I added an unnecessary line. Please ignore the range = (1, number) definition and var.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

Comment: Also, you may want to edit your first line. Technically a positive whole number would be `(>=1)` not `(<1)`.

Comment: I read the post and it did'nt help me. I will fix the error or >1 and <1 thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the modulo operator `%`:

```
>>> 5 % 3
2
>>> 15 % 5
0
```

Specifically `a % b == 0` iff `b` divides `a` without remainder. Otherwise the remainder is returned.

Comment: ok so I would put      if f % number == 0  
                                      print(f)
                                      number /= f
                                 else:
                                       f += 1

Comment: Yes that would work. If the answer answered your question please accept the answer.

Comment: Correction, it would have to be if number $ f == 0:

Comment: It wont let me accept the answer yet. I will accept the answer as you have helped me to the point of success. Thank you!