# Write a function that tests if a number is divisible by n

Tags: python

```
def div(num1,num2):
  n = 0
  while n > 0:
    if num1%n == 0 and num2%n==0:
        print(True)
        n+=1
    else:
        print(False)
```

This is probably wrong though.

EDIT:

```
def div(num1,num2):
if num1%num2==0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Give proper intendation from n=0 onwards

Comment: What are you trying to do? You seem to be doing more than just testing if a number is divisible by *n*.

Comment: That loop is never run because `n` always is 0. And if you changed the condition to `n >= 0`, that's just an infinite loop. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: maybe it should be n<maxPreferred? since it is always a 0 it  will not go in while loop

Comment: @Jerfov2 `n >= 0` wouldn't make it an infinite loop. It would crash right away.

Comment: @StefanPochmann why would it "crash"?

Comment: @Jerfov2 `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`

Comment: @StefanPochmann Nice catch, I didn't see that. This is broken is more ways than one ;)

Comment: Technically any real number is divisible by any non-zero real number... Are you looking for only numbers whose modulus with `n` is `0`?

Comment: possible exact dupe of [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

Comment: remove all the business with `n = 0`, `while n > 0:` and `n+=1`, you just need the one line `if num1 % num2 == 0:`, then put quotes around `"True"`, and `"False"`

Comment: @downshift yes, I got it thank you so much. i know this is broken. This was my first semester in coding and i'm learning more and more everyday. this is what I have now and it is great. I was overcomplicating it. Thank you guys for everything!

Comment: def div(num1,num2):
    if num1%num2==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: @IbrahimChalhoub, no problem, glad you figured it out, cheers! :)

Comment: @downshift I just have a couple quick questions about python

what do you think? 
1. How many arguments are required to call a function?




# 2. How many values are required to return from a function?

I put at least one argument for calling a function and at least one value required to return from a function. I can't see how this is incorrect. Please correct me if I'm wrong as I am new to functions.

Comment: @IbrahimChalhoub, No arguments are required for call to or return from functions. However, if you specify parameters in a function's signature, then that same number of parameters are required when you call the function. Same with returning values from a function, functions aren't required to return any value, but if you call a function and try to use a return value, but don't return anything from the function then it will error. But none are required.

Comment: @IbrahimChalhoub you can have functions with no arguments and no return that you call to change the state of a global variable

Comment: Hm, so I guess the technical answer is none to both.

Answer (score 0):

this question is good use for ternary return

```
def div(number, n):
    # check if denominator is zero or modulo not 0
    return False if ((n==0) or (number%n!=0)) else True

print div(10,0),div(0,10),div(2,10),div(10,2)

>>>False True False True
```

possible duplicate

[How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Not quite there in my lecture lol, just reached functions as of the week before last. But thanks anyway! :)