# Check whether X is divisible by Y, i.e. no remainder

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that takes numbers from  user (a and b) then 
 the program will count up from 1 to x (which is a) and output whether the number in each iteration is divisible by y (which is b) or not.

```
    //while loop deciding if a is divided by b
    for (count = 1; count <= a; count++) {
        if (a / b == 0) {
            printf("%d is divisible by %d\n", a, b);
        } 
        else if (a / b != 0) {
            printf("%d is not divisible by %d\n", a, b);
        }
    }
   return 0 ;
}
```

but when i enter 10 for a and 2 for b the output is

```
10 is not divisible by 2
```

ten times

how can i change the code so that each iteration is checked?

Comment: Why would you expect a different result if you use the same `a` and `b` values for each iteration? Can you figure out which variable is the one that is actually changing on each iteration?

Comment: The title of question is misleading

Comment: First of all `a%b == 0` means a is divisible by b. You want to fix that. Also can you point out the need for the loop. You want same message to be printed total a time? Lastly `if` and `else if` conditions are exact opposite. You don't need `else if`. Simple `else` will do

Comment: Check here http://ideone.com/PkxgK0

Comment: Do not vandalize your question by deleting the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

Comment: did you ever go to google and search for "C check divisibility"?

Answer (score 3):

First - `a / b` tells how many times `a` can be divided by `b`, e.g. `9 / 2` will give you `4`.

To know whether the division produces a reminder, you must use `a % b == 0`. Example: `9 % 2` will give you `1` while `8 % 2` will give you `0`.

Next - You keep using `a` and `b` for the calculation inside the loop. You need to use `count` instead of `a`. This applies to the `printf`as well.

And - You don't need a condition on the `else` part.

Try something like:

```
for (count = 1; count <= a; count++) {
    if (count % b == 0) {
        printf("%d is divisible by %d\n", count, b);
    } 
    else {
        printf("%d is not divisible by %d\n", count, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter a 2-digit number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n%d is even.", i);
        }
        else if (i%2 != 0)
        {
            printf("\n%d is odd.",i);
        }
        
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code for checking whether the number is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has two logical errors -

- You are running a `for` loop to go from `1` to `a`, but are not using the loop variable `count` anywhere inside the loop.
- `a/b == 0` cannot be used to check if `b` divides `a`, instead use `a%b == 0`. `%` is modulus operator which returns the remainder when `a` is divided by `b`.
  Correct Code -

  ```
  for (count = 1; count <= a; count++) {
     if (count%b == 0) {
        printf("%d is divisible by %d\n", count, b);
     } 
     else {
         printf("%d is not divisible by %d\n", count, b);
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

every iteration you are using same values, then you can use count variable and at last print value of variable.
you can write like this,

```
for (count = 1; count <= a; count++)
    {
            if (count % b == 0)
            {
                    printf("%d is divisible by %d\n", a, b);
                    n += 1;
            }
    }
    printf("count : %d\n",n);
```

it will show the count.

Comment: your answer doesn't fix the problem of not using `count`

Comment: am using variable 'n' for count. it will count the no. of times that division takes place.

Comment: which doesn't have any relation to the problem - go read the other answers and see why they're correct and this one isn't