# How to filter all data that is not divisible by n in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, filter

In this case n=100

Here's my dataset

```
id   amount
1    1000
2    2000
3    2300.7632
4    4560
```

What I want is

```
id   amount
3    2300.7632
4    4560
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with modulo `%`:

```
df = df[df['amount'] % 100 != 0]
print (df)
   id     amount
2   3  2300.7632
3   4  4560.0000
```

Same as:

```
df = df[df['amount'].mod(100).ne(0)]
print (df)
   id     amount
2   3  2300.7632
3   4  4560.0000
```

Detail:

```
print (df['amount'].mod(100))
0     0.0000
1     0.0000
2     0.7632
3    60.0000
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

It is practically implemented [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002234/2901002) in pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
In [1787]: df[(df.amount % 100).astype(bool)]
Out[1787]:
   id     amount
2   3  2300.7632
3   4  4560.0000
```

Comment: Same as `df[(df.amount % 100).ne(0)]`

Answer (score 2):

```
In [79]: d[d.amount % 100 > 0]
Out[79]:
   id     amount
2   3  2300.7632
3   4  4560.0000
```