# Cant Get Proper Output To This Program

Tags: python

I'm trying to print numbers if they are not divisible by three or five and if they are divisible by three or five they should not be printed.
This is my code:

```
i = int(input())
if (i == i/3) | (i == i/5):
    print('this number is divisible by 3 or 5')
else:
    print('i')
```

Im new to stackoverflow does not the properly how it works!!!!:(

Comment: You must include a [mre] in your question. A photograph of your monitor is not appropriate.

Comment: Dear old [fizz buzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz)

Comment: "This is my code". Can't see it buddy.

Comment: You have to have a look at python basics, maybe with a course from 0. `If` should not be uppercase, `:` missing, wrong quotations mark, no indentation...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

Answer (score 0):

If `i = 5`, then your if statement becomes

```
if (5 == 5/3) or (5 == 1):
    # do stuff
```

You're looking for the modulus `%`, which gives you the remainder of a division. Change the if statement to

```
if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
```

and it should work. For `i = 5` this will give

```
if (2 == 0) or (0 == 0):
    # do stuff
```