# How do I check if the answer of the division shown in the code is divisible by 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm aiming to check if b / a's answer is divisible by 2, and if it is - it will print yes.

```
   a = int(input())
   b = int(input())
   if b / a #is divisible by 2
         print("Yes.")
   else:
         print("No.")
```

Comment: `if (b / a) % 2 == 0`

Comment: thank you! im still new the percentage sign's use in python and it confuses me tbh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python)

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if (b / a) % 2 == 0:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [modulo](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html)(%) so for this example `if (b/a)%2 == 0:`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `ternary operator` to combine the if/else statement into a single print statement like this:

```
print("yes" if (b / a) % 2 == 0 else "no")
```

You can also do it in a branchless fashion to decrease complexity and increase speed:

```
print("yes" * ((b/a) % 2 == 0) + "no" * (not (b/a) % 2 == 0))
```

This works because `False` has an `int` value of `0`, therefore `"text" * False = ""`

Similarly, `"text" * True = "text"`