# Add a time delay in python count up function for the multiples of a given number

Tags: python, python-3.x

My function is:

```
import time

count = int()

while True:
  count += 1
  time.sleep(1)
  if count == 50:
    time.sleep(5)
```

I need to put a time delay in every multiple of 50.

Comment: I was about to say that, but I hoped the loop would be in the `do some function` pseudocode he provided.

Comment: just use sleep method : `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: [how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

Comment: Your core question seems to be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number-python

Comment: I did not make you hurry :) you posted a incomplete & erroneous [mre] of your problem - I merely commented on it and you fixed it - now all looks fine and it may help others after you.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Actually am a new one to this stack. Am learning something here.. ! Thanks for the improvisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

count = int()

<
count += 1
do some function
>

if (count % 50) == 0:
  time.sleep(5)
```

This should do it.

Comment: There is no loop, your count will never reach 50. Your code is also broken and does not run as it is invalid python code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
import time
for count in range(1000):
    if count %50==0:
        print ('Number divisible by 50')
        time.sleep(5)
```