# How to manage huge divisions – integer division result too large for a float

Tags: python, math, numbers

I've been trying to make a python script that tells if a number is a prime number or not. I've tried by my own way, but I ran into a big problem.

When I'm trying to divide a big number it gives me a error `OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float`. I found that if I use `//` method at the divide it stops giving me that error, but I can't find a way to find if the number is prime.

This is the first script I made, that gave the `OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float`:

```
product = 1      
list = []
i = 13
for num in range(i):
    list.append(num)

list = [x for x in list if x != 0]

for x in list:
    product *= x

final = product + 1
final2 = final/i

if float.is_integer(final2) == True:
    print("Prime")
else:
    print("Not prime")
```

As you can see, I used to divide the `final` by `i`. If the number was a prime one, it will return  `float.is_integer`. But if the `i` variable was a big number, it will give the error.
Then I used the `//` method but I have no idea how to check if the the number is prime.
Here is the second scrpt, it's the same but replacin the `/` for a `//`:

```
list = []
i = 17
for num in range(i):
    list.append(num)

list = [x for x in list if x != 0]

for x in list:
    product *= x

final = product + 1
final2 = final//i

if final2%1 == 0: #Here I have no idea of how to check if is a prime
    print("Prime")
else:
    print("Not prime")
```

I know this is not the best way to check if a number is prime.

Comment: It sounds as though what you want is a way to tell whether an integer is exactly divisible by another integer. The safe way to do that is to use the modulo operator `%`. For example, `final` is divisible by `i` if and only if `final % i == 0`. That way you avoid the use of floating-point arithmetic entirely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check whether a number is divisible by another number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002217/how-do-you-check-whether-a-number-is-divisible-by-another-number)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to check for prime numbers, as discussed [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number). I've tested it several times with known prime and composite numbers and it was right each time. I've also changed it to test the numbers smaller than the square root of the number so it didn't go through every number up to itself.

```
# Program to check if a number is prime or not
from math import sqrt

# To take input from the user
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

# define a flag variable
flag = False

if num == 1:
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
elif num > 1:
    # check for factors
    for i in range(2, round(sqrt(num))):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            # if factor is found, set flag to True
            flag = True
            # break out of loop
            break

    # check if flag is True
    if flag:
        print(num, "is a composite number")
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
```