# How to print if number is not whole python 3.5.7

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to write a program where the print statement will print only if the number is not a whole number.

if (yr/4) #is not a whole number

print("this is not a whole number")

Comment: `if yr % 4 != 0:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining whether an value is a whole number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239967/determining-whether-an-value-is-a-whole-number-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

```
num = # any number here

if int(num) != num: # check if number is not whole (same if you truncate)
    print('Not a whole number')
```

This should do the trick